# Perhaps this inequality is established:$\sum_{k=1}^{n}ka_{k-1}a_{k}\le 2\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}a_{i}a_{j}$

Tags: inequality

Let $a_{i},i=0，1,2,3,\cdots$ ，where $a_{0}=0$,and such $0\le a_{k+1}-a_{k}\le 1,k=1,2,3,\cdots,n$

prove or disprove 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}ka_{k-1}a_{k}\le 2\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}a_{i}a_{j}\tag{1}$$

I try to apply   $$a_{k+1}>a_{k}$$
since
$$a_{k+1}-a_{k}\le 1$$ Thus it remains 
$$a_{2}-a_{1}\le 1$$
$$a_{3}-a_{2}\le 1$$
\cdots
$$a_{k+1}-a_{k}\le 1$$
so 
$$a_{k}\le k-1$$.But How prove it $(1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n=2$, $(1)$ holds.

For $n\ge 3$, $(1)$ does not hold when
$$a_1=a_2=\cdots =a_{n-2}=0,\quad a_{n-1}=a_n=1$$
since then we have
$$(1)\iff na_{n-1}a_n\le 2a_{n-1}a_{n}\iff n\le 2$$